# Concatenating a list of numbers into one integer in haskell

Tags: haskell, concatenation

I am doing yet another Project Euler problem - [Problem 38](https://projecteuler.net/problem=38).
I have this function which returns a list of numbers but what I need is that list of numbers to be one number. It calculates the concatenated product of an integer.

```
f (a,b) = a*b
conProInt x n  = map f (zip (replicate n x) ([1..n]))

prob38 = maximum [ (conProInt (x) (n)) | x <- [100..500], n <- [1..9], (sort $ nub $ (decToList $ (conProInt x n) )) == (sort $ (decToList $ (conProInt x n) )), (sort $ nub $ (decToList $ (conProInt x n))) == [1..9] ]
```

eg:

```
conProInt 192 3
```

returns:
    [192,384,576]

what I need returned is:
    192384576

I have searched around and can't find a function or think of a function I could construct that would deliver what I need. How would I go about this?

EDIT:

I have updated the script to incorporate faster concatenation, but it doesn't return the correct result:

```
f (a,b) = a*b
conProInt x n  =( combine (map f (zip (replicate n x) ([1..n]))))
prob38 = maximum [ (conProInt (x) (n)) | x <- [1..50000], n <- [2..40], (sort $ nub $ (decToList $ (conProInt x n) )) == (sort $ (decToList $ (conProInt x n) )), (sort $ nub $ (decToList $ (conProInt x n))) == [1..9] ]
```

I'm pretty sure the pandigital test

```
(sort $ nub $ (decToList $ (conProInt x n) )) == (sort $ (decToList $ (conProInt x n) )), (sort $ nub $ (decToList $ (conProInt x n))) == [1..9]
```

won't fail. I tried to make the search as large as possible, but the maximum 9-pandigital I got was 986315724. Any suggestions? Is the range of values for n a very large one?

Comment: `map f $ zip (replicate n x) [1..n]` == `map f $ zip (repeat x) [1..n]` == `zipWith (f x) [1..n]`, and your pandigital test could be shortened to `sort (decToList $ conProInt x n) == [1..9]`.  Your bounds are actually a bit too wide (`n>9` makes no sense and given `n` you can narrow the range of `x`) but really you should try to figure out how you managed to produce 986315724: it's not actually a concatenated product of an integer with `[1..n]`.  Possibly your `combine` or `decToList` is still wrong.

Comment: Could it be that Haskell is getting confused with the large numbers and the use of Int. But it doesn't like it when I try to change the classes to Integer. I'll have to look further into functions that use Integer.

Comment: The `length` et al. set of functions return `Int`, thus doing mixing them into your arithmetic requires everything to be typed `Int`.  Your options are to use `Data.List.genericLength` et al. which return a generic `Num` instance, or to use `toInteger` which... well, the name is pretty obvious.  That being said, 987654321 only requires 30 bits to represent and should fit into an Int just fine, so that's unlikely to be your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going via `String`s is probably easiest:

```
read $ concat $ map (show) [192,384,576]
```

Though you'll probably need to add a type signature:

```
Prelude> (read $ concat $ map (show) [192,384,576]) :: Int
192384576
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting some rather strange behaviour. On typing `conProInt 93 5` as a sample, it returned the answer: -1626048847. What could be the cause?

Comment: @Jonno: Integer overflow. 32-bit integers — even unsigned ones — can only represent numbers in the low billions. The result of that function is much higher.

Comment: @Jonno: If `Int` is too small, try using `Integer` instead. Or, if you want to make it a function, any type in `Num` will work:

    concatDigits :: (Num m, Show m, Num n, Read n) => [m] -> n
    concatDigits = read . concat . map (show)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this function to concatenate a list of numbers:

```
concatNumbers :: [Int] -> String
concatNumbers = concat . map show
```

If you want the function to return the concatenation as a number, you can use `read`.

Comment: concat . map = concatMap, no?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to concatenate digits without converting to and from character strings.

```
-- foldl1' is a strict fold.  "foldl1" would also work...
import Data.List (foldl1')    

-- Combine two numbers such that their digits are concatenated.
-- op 1 23 = 123, op 0 12 = 12, op 12345 67 = 1234567
op :: Int -> Int -> Int
op a b = a * power 10 (numDigits b) + b

-- How many digits does a positive number have?
numDigits :: Int -> Int
numDigits x = length . takeWhile (>= 1) . iterate (`div` 10) $ x

-- Take a positive number and raise it to a positive power.
-- power 5 2 = 25, power 10 3 = 1000
power :: Int -> Int -> Int
power x y = foldl1' (*) . take y $ repeat x

-- Take a list of numbers, and concatenate all their digits.
combine :: [Int] -> Int
combine xs = foldl1' op xs
```

example run:

```
Prelude> :m +Data.List
Prelude Data.List> let power x y = foldl1' (*) . take y $ repeat x
Prelude Data.List> let numDigits = length . takeWhile (>=1) . iterate (`div` 10)
Prelude Data.List> let op a b = a * power 10 (numDigits b) + b
Prelude Data.List> let combine xs = foldl1' op xs
Prelude Data.List> combine [192, 384, 576]
192384576
Prelude Data.List>
```

Comment: That assumes numbers between 100 and 999, actually.  Which, luckily, should be the case when solving Project Euler problem 38, but still...

Comment: ephemient: You're right.  He asked for concatenation, and I gave him a way to combine digits representing different 'places' (millions, thousands, etc.) instead.

It's been rewritten to concatenate any list of positive Ints.

Comment: `power = (^)`, and I'd personally write `numDigits x = fromJust $ findIndex (> x) $ iterate (*10) 1` because integer multiplication is faster than integer division, but now I'm just nitpicking :)

Comment: (^) is good to know about.  It's defined in GHC.Real, which for some reason doesn't appear at http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/index.html.  Now I can stop writing that by hand all over the place.

Both of our numDigits are pretty inefficient since they generate a list to do their work.

Comment: `(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a` and `(**) :: (Floating a) => a -> a -> a` are both defined in `Prelude`.  I'd like to think that my `numDigits` is also more efficient because it uses a constant list that can be lifted out and shared, but I haven't checked what GHC does -- it might be smart enough to skip constructing the list altogether.

Comment: I posted some benchmarks at http://blog.michaelsteele.us/2009/10/optimization-with-criterion/

Comment: @Michael, thank for that optimisation there, but after running the program I keep getting an incorrect solution. I have editted my main post with the updated script.

Comment: @Jonno_FTW That would be because of a bug in my code.  numDigits6 x = SF.length . SF.takeWhile (<= x) $ SF.iterate (*10) 1.  I'll update the post tonight, and actually check that they all give the correct answer this time.